pgAdmin4 не соединяется с сервером PostgreSQL
На виртуальной машине развернул Ubuntu Server 20.06. Поставил PostgreSQL 15 и pgAdmin4.
Отредактировал pg_hba.cong, ipv4 - connection сделал trust для: 127.0.0.1/32.
Отредактировал postgresql.conf, добавил в конец файла: listen_addresses = '*', порт 5432.
Статус службы postgresql - active.
ifconfig выводит:
enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:feae:be4d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:ae:be:4d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 214517  bytes 303290671 (303.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 41312  bytes 2679233 (2.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

В pgAdmin4 пытаюсь создать подключение в postgreSQL, через адрес 10.0.2.15, под пользователем postgres, получаю ошибку:

Unable to connection to server: connection failed: connection refused is the server running on that host accepting tcp/ip connections?

Подскажите, что еще нужно прописать, чтобы подключиться к pgAdmin4?

Со стоковым фаерволом договорились? Тормознуть UFW если оживет добавить правило.
